# Difference between every pair of columns of two numpy arrays (how to do it more efficiently)?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I am trying to optimize some code, and by profiling i noticed that this particular loop takes a lot of time. Can you help me write it faster?

```
import numpy as np

rows_a, rows_v, cols = (10, 15, 3)
a = np.arange(rows_a*cols).reshape(rows_a,cols)
v = np.arange(rows_v*cols).reshape(rows_v,cols)

c = 0
for i in range(len(v)):
    D = ((a-v[i])**2).sum(axis=-1)
    c += D.min()

print(c)
```

Is there any numpy function that can do this efficiently?

Comment: What is `a`? Is it a float or an array? If it is an array, what is it's shape? And what is the shape of `v`?

Comment: I added some dummy data to make it clear. The code is executable now. Apologies for my lack of clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

rows_a, rows_v, cols = (10, 15, 3)
a = np.arange(rows_a*cols).reshape(rows_a,cols)
v = np.arange(rows_v*cols).reshape(rows_v,cols)

def using_loop():
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(v)):
        D = ((a-v[i])**2).sum(axis=-1)
        c += D.min()
    return c

def using_broadcasting():
    return ((a[:,np.newaxis,:]-v)**2).sum(axis=-1).min(axis=0).sum()
```

---

```
In [106]: %timeit using_loop()
1000 loops, best of 3: 233 µs per loop

In [107]: %timeit using_broadcasting()
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.1 µs per loop

In [108]: assert using_loop() == using_broadcasting()
```

---

When using NumPy it usually helps to eliminate `for-loops` (if possible) and express the calculation with operations done on entire arrays -- or at least on arrays that are as large as possible. By doing so, you off-load more of the work to fast algorithms written in C or Fortran without intermediate Python code.

In the original code, `D` has shape `(10,)` for each iteration of the loop. Since there are 15 iterations of the loop, if we could express all the values for `D` from all 15 iterations at once as one big array, then `D` would have shape `(10, 15)`. In fact, we can do that:

Since `a` has shape `(10,3)`, `a[:, np.newaxis, :]` has shape `(10,1,3)`.

Using [NumPy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), since `v` has shape `(15,3)`,

```
a[:,np.newaxis,:]-v
```

has shape `(10,15,3)`. Squaring, then summing on the last axis gives an array of shape `(10, 15)`. This is the new `D`:

```
In [109]: ((a[:,np.newaxis,:]-v)**2).sum(axis=-1).shape
Out[109]: (10, 15)
```

Once you have `D`, the rest of the calculation follows naturally.